# How to make hidden contents important for google?

Tags: seo, google-search, hidden-text

I am using a book plugin to showing some contents.

At first all of pages except first one are hidden. But my contents are in other pages that are hidden.

My solution is to write all of my contents again in a `p` tag and set a position style for it that users can't see it.

```
style="position: absolute; right: -2000px;"
```

This way the users can not see the contents but Google can see. Is it the way or any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599933/googlebot-and-hidden-content-inside-dynamically-shown-js-based-tabs-within-a) and I like `Zachary Schuessler` answer. I tested my page with the tool mentioned and I saw google crawlers is seeing my hidden contents.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to show content to Google and not users, you'll be trouble because that's [cloaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking).

Search engines are actually crawling your content for it's users so if these end users can't see the content then whats the point.

May be you could provide some sample of you book, which can also be crawlable.

Comment: Thanks. I showed a link in my question. I am using a flipping jquery book plugin. All of my contents in it is important but for some reasons I want to use book plugins. Actually the thing that the users see is the same with the one which crawlers see. But users see them in flipping book and the crawlers see it in a sipmle tag. Is it cloaking yet?